# Extract rows from a list of data frames

Tags: r

I have the following list, for example:

```
> res
[[1]]
   A B freq
1 11 2    1
2 11 3    1
3 13 4    1
4 42 5    1
5 51 5    3

[[2]]
   A B   C freq
1 11 2 432    1
2 11 3 432    1
3 13 4 241    1
4 42 5   2    1
5 51 5 332    3
```

I would like to have a generic method for any list, in order to get a list with the rows with "(freq) > (specific value)" or the head rows with the biggest freq.

If I want the rows with "(freq) > 1" or the freq top2 rows, the output would be something like this:

```
> output
 [[1]]
    A B freq
   51 5    3

 [[2]]
    A B   C freq
   51 5 332    3
```

I can get it like the following way, but it is not the case, because I can have a big list:

```
> res[[1]][5,]
   A B freq
5 51 5    3
> res[[2]][5,]
   A B   C freq
5 51 5 332    3
```

I would be grateful for any help you can provide

I have got several good answers. I have tried them and I am going to show the time results here (I am not sure that this is the right way, but it can help other users)

```
> system.time({
+ result=lapply(res, subset, freq > 100)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.00    0.14 
> system.time({
+ purrr::map(res, ~ .x %>% filter(freq > 100))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
    1.7     0.0     1.7 
> system.time({
+ purrr::map(res, function(x) {
+   x[which.max(x[["freq"]]), ]
+ })
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.05 
> system.time({
+ threshold <- 1
+ purrr::map(res, function(x) {
+   x[x[["freq"]] > threshold, ]
+ })
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.19    0.00    0.18
```

Comment: Just do `lapply(res, subset, freq > 1)`  or with `tidyverse` `map(res, ~ .x %>% filter(freq > 1))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much akrun, it works very well, you and ruaridhw have given me several ways to do the same. I am going to try it with big lists to see the fastest way. My doubt is how I can divide and order the output by freq and have just rows as list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a list of data frames with one row containing the largest frequency use `purrr::map`:

```
purrr::map(res, function(x) {
  x[which.max(x[["freq"]]), ]
})
```

Similarly modify the internal function to filter on `freq > some_value`

eg.

```
threshold <- 1
purrr::map(res, function(x) {
  x[x[["freq"]] > threshold, ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ruaridhw. The second way works better, because it returns all the data frame rows with the same biggest value. In this case, my doubt is how I can divide and order the output by freq and have just rows as list elements.

Answer (score 0):

this is the list i have used 
a=list(id=c(1,2,3,4))

use unlist for that to get data frame
a1 <- data.frame(unlist(a[1]))

Comment: Thanks Nithin, but this is not what I was asking for. This answer is just in case I wanted to order all list values.